# Build one list out of two with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am building an application to firstly copy data from one Workbook to another (this is working already).

Then comes the most complicated part that I am not sure yet if it is even possible. 
There are two lists of data.

First one (Sheet1):

[image]

Second one (Sheet2):

[image]

Code should compare columns B and C and build new list to (Sheet3) that will look like this:

[image]

So first build Sheet3, after comparison, if duplicate has been found then add value to corresponding (column B). If duplicate not found, then make new line with data.

Here is my code to detect duplicates.

```
Sub CheckAvailability()
Dim rMyRng As Range, rCompare As Range, r As Range, lFound As Long, blStatus As Boolean

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rMyRng = .Range("B2:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)
End With

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rCompare = .Range("B2:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)
End With

For Each r In rMyRng.Rows
    With r
        .Select
        blStatus = False
        lFound = Application.CountIfs(rCompare.Columns(1), .Cells(1).Value, rCompare.Columns(2), .Cells(2).Value)
        If lFound Then blStatus = True
        .Cells(2).Offset(, 1).Value = blStatus
    End With
Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

With my current code I get this as an output, that is correct. How to make all the rest working?

[image]

Comment: Maybe via a simple class module and a collection/dictionary?

Comment: You want VBA Code for this or you are open to do this manually? If you want to do this manually, it is pretty simple. **[1.]** Copy `Number` column in respective sheets and temporarily insert it after the `Name` Column **[2.]** Copy Names from both sheets and put it in say column A in a new sheet. Click on `Data|Remove Duplicates` **[3.]**. Add Number1 in Col B and Number2 in Col C in the new sheet. Use Vlookup to get numbers from both sheets.

Comment: If you want to do it via VBA then
**[1.]** Store data from both sheets in 2 different arrays
**[2.]** Create a unique collection of names from both arrays
**[3.]** Create a 3rd array for output
**[4.]** Use 3 Loops to search data and store output in 3rd array
**[5.]** First loop through the collection
**[6.]** Inside the first loop, use a second loop to search the first array
**[7.]** Inside the first loop, use a third loop to search the second array
**[8.]** Output 3rd array to new worksheet

Comment: Does it have to be VBA? I believe a sumproduct could do this, given that you copy paste everything in to one sheet.

Comment: Yes, it have to be VBA because I want to built VBS and run it daily on Virtual Desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way as it's quite extensive, but felt like trying some dictionary =). Hopefully it's helpfull.

---

***Arrays with Dictionary (concatenated)***

- Makes use of two arrays that are populated from both lists
- Iterates over the first array to load items into a dictionary
- Iterates over the second array to check if they exist in the dictionary. If so check for the Post Box number and act accordingly
- Iterates through the dictionary to transpose it's values into sheet3

---

```
Sub BuildList()

'Declare all the variables
Dim x As Long, arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'Fill 1st array from sheet1
With Sheet1
    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    arr1 = .Range("A2:C" & x).Value
End With

'Fill 2nd array from sheet2
With Sheet2
    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    arr2 = .Range("A2:C" & x).Value
End With

'Load 1st array into dictionary
For x = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    dict.Add arr1(x, 2), arr1(x, 1) & "||" & arr1(x, 2) & "|" & arr1(x, 3)
Next x

'Load 2nd array into dictionary with test
For x = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
    If dict.Exists(arr2(x, 2)) Then
        If Trim(arr2(x, 3)) = Split(dict(arr2(x, 2)), "|")(3) Then
            dict(arr2(x, 2)) = Split(dict(arr2(x, 2)), "|")(0) & "|" & arr2(x, 1) & "|" & arr2(x, 2) & "|" & arr2(x, 3)
        Else
            dict.Add arr2(x, 2) & "x", "|" & arr2(x, 1) & "|" & arr2(x, 2) & "|" & arr2(x, 3)
        End If
    Else
        dict.Add arr2(x, 2), "|" & arr2(x, 1) & "|" & arr2(x, 2) & "|" & arr2(x, 3)
    End If
Next x

'Transpose dictionary into sheet3
With Sheet3
    x = 2
    For Each Key In dict.keys
        .Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = Split(dict(Key), "|")
        x = x + 1
    Next Key
End With

End Sub
```

---

***Arrays with Dictionary (class module)***

A second option, as per my comment, is to also include a class module. Simply add the following class module, and name is `clssList`:

```
Public Number1 As Variant
Public Number2 As Variant
Public NameSpec As String
Public PostBox As Long
```

Now instead of the previous code, we can set new objects through this classmodule and populate our dictionary with them:

```
Sub BuildListWithClss()

'Declare all the variables
Dim x As Long, arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, lst As clssList
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'Fill 1st array from sheet1
With Sheet1
    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    arr1 = .Range("A2:C" & x).Value
End With

'Fill 2nd array from sheet2
With Sheet2
    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    arr2 = .Range("A2:C" & x).Value
End With

'Load 1st array into dictionary with use of class
For x = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    Set lst = New clssList
    lst.Number1 = arr1(x, 1)
    lst.NameSpec = arr1(x, 2)
    lst.PostBox = arr1(x, 3)
    dict.Add arr1(x, 2), lst
Next x

'Load 2nd array into dictionary with test
For x = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
    If dict.Exists(arr2(x, 2)) Then
        If Trim(arr2(x, 3)) = Trim(dict(arr2(x, 2)).PostBox) Then
            dict(arr2(x, 2)).Number2 = arr2(x, 1)
        Else
            Set lst = New clssList
            lst.Number2 = arr2(x, 1)
            lst.NameSpec = arr2(x, 2)
            lst.PostBox = arr2(x, 3)
            dict.Add arr1(x, 2) & "x", lst
        End If
    Else
        Set lst = New clssList
        lst.Number2 = arr2(x, 1)
        lst.NameSpec = arr2(x, 2)
        lst.PostBox = arr2(x, 3)
        dict.Add arr2(x, 2), lst
    End If
Next x

'Transpose dictionary into sheet3
With Sheet3
    x = 2
    For Each Key In dict.keys
        .Cells(x, 1).Value = dict(Key).Number1
        .Cells(x, 2).Value = dict(Key).Number2
        .Cells(x, 3).Value = dict(Key).NameSpec
        .Cells(x, 4).Value = dict(Key).PostBox
        x = x + 1
    Next Key
End With
```

As you can see, a bit more code. But IMO it's rather clean and easy to understand and it won't bite you when one of your names include a pipe symbol as my previous code would.

Comment: This works! Now I have to spend some time to understand how :)

Comment: @user7202022, step through the code using `F8` for better understanding. I tried to write it as such, that it's "easy" to understand (I hope) =)

Answer (score 2):

another dictionary solution (not tested):

```
Sub Main()
    Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim cell As Range
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            dict(cell.Offset(, 1).Value2 & "|" & cell.Offset(, 2).Value2) = cell.Value2 & " "
        Next
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For Each cell In .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            dict(cell.Offset(, 1).Value2 & "|" & cell.Offset(, 2).Value2) = dict(cell.Offset(, 1).Value2 & "|" & cell.Offset(, 2).Value2) & " " & cell.Value2
        Next
    End With

    Dim key As Variant
    Dim iRow As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet3")
        For Each key In dict.Keys
            .Range("A1:B1").Offset(iRow).Value = Split(Replace(dict(key), "  ", " "), " ")
            .Range("C1:D1").Offset(iRow).Value = Split(key, "|")
            iRow = iRow + 1
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This almost works but splitting words from sentences (if more than 2 words) on output Sheet. Must be something with Split code. Haven't investigated yet

Comment: Works now! Unfortunately I can't mark both as an answer... :/ This is a lack of this website that if both are good working solutions why you should choose one of them...

Comment: leave things as they are. which solution are you going to use?

Comment: Very clean approach. Only thing I would like to do personally is looping through arrays instead of cells. + =)

Comment: Thanks @JvdV. As for the array looping, it would be certainly faster, but would dirty the code, too...