# (VBA) How to delete dupicate row and sum corresponding values to right columns?

Tags: excel, vba, sum, duplicates

I have an 'test' excel where I have 4 columns from A-D. If A and B values are same with another row, macro deletes 'older' row and sums corresponding values to another row in to columns C and D.

```
      A | B | C | D                         A | B | C | D 

 1    1 | 2 | 1 | 5                         2 | 3 | 2 | 5
 2    2 | 3 | 2 | 5                         2 | 6 | 2 | 5
 3    2 | 6 | 2 | 5      After Macro        1 | 2 | 4 | 9
 4    1 | 2 | 3 | 4      --------->         5 | 4 | 1 | 2
 5    5 | 4 | 1 | 2
```

EDITED! So here row 1 and row 4 had same values on columns A and B so macro deletes row 1 and adds row 1 column C D values to row 4 columns C D !!

I have tried with this code, but now it only adds values only to column D and not also to column C.. I really dont know how to do it.. Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim i As Long, lrk As Long, tmp As Variant, vals As Variant

        With Worksheets(1)
            tmp = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Value2
            ReDim vals(LBound(tmp, 1) To UBound(tmp, 1), 1 To 1)
            For i = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1)
                vals(i, 1) = Application.SumIfs(.Columns(3), .Columns(1), tmp(i, 1), Columns(2), tmp(i, 2), Columns(3), tmp(i, 3), Columns(4), tmp(i, 4))

            Next i
            .Cells(2, "D").Resize(UBound(vals, 1), UBound(vals, 2)) = vals
            With .Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion
                .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4), Header:=xlYes
            End With
        End With
    End Sub
```

Actual excel has almost 2000 rows.. so I also hope this macro is fast enough for that. Thank you for your help and Im sorry for my English. I hope you understand :)

Comment: Can you put a snippet of example data, or a link to a sample file? With before and after what you want to see.

Comment: Hi @cameront :) I edited my post. Hope this is more clear now..

Comment: Maybe some class module with a dictionary? That should be fast. Redim really isnt. I'll see if I can throw together some quick example.

Comment: Thank you @JvdV ! I would really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oke, the answer is heavily based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58352689/9758194) recent answer I have given. There is another clever answer in the same thread by @DisplayName that you might want to utilize, but here is my take on a understandable way of using a class module and a dictionary.

---

Let's assume the following input data starting from `A1`:

```
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 4 | 1 | 2 |
```

**First** create a `class` module and name it, e.g.: `clssList` with the following code in it:

```
Public Col1 As Variant
Public Col2 As Variant
Public Col3 As Variant
Public Col4 As Variant
```

**Second** create a module, and put the following code in it:

```
Sub BuildList()

Dim x As Long, arr As Variant, lst As clssList
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'Fill array variable from sheet
With Sheet1
    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A1:D" & x).Value
End With

'Load array into dictionary with use of class
For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2)) Then
        Set lst = New clssList
        lst.Col1 = arr(x, 1)
        lst.Col2 = arr(x, 2)
        lst.Col3 = arr(x, 3)
        lst.Col4 = arr(x, 4)
        dict.Add arr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2), lst
    Else 'In case column 2 is the same then add the values to the lst object
        dict(arr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2)).Col3 = dict(arr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2)).Col3 + arr(x, 3)
        dict(arr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2)).Col4 = dict(arr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2)).Col4 + arr(x, 4)
    End If
Next x

'Transpose dictionary into sheet3
With Sheet1
    x = 1
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        .Cells(x, 6).Value = dict(Key).Col1
        .Cells(x, 7).Value = dict(Key).Col2
        .Cells(x, 8).Value = dict(Key).Col3
        .Cells(x, 9).Value = dict(Key).Col4
        x = x + 1
    Next Key
End With

End Sub
```

It's a bit extensive but I have written in such a way it will be easy to understand what is going on. It should be prety fast for 20000 records.

---

The above results in a matrix starting from range `F1` looking like:

[image]

---

> *Running a speed test on 100.000 rows returned a total elapsed time of around 3,4 seconds. 20.000 Records came down to around 1,8 seconds.*

---

Another, shorter (written code, not speed) way would be to not use a class module and concatenate array items (with a small risk that the delimiter you will be using exists in a value). An example is shown in the link on the top. And I just see that @RonRosenFeld put an example up on how to use just that.

Comment: While doing some timing (see my comment below), I noticed that your routine does not return the rows in the same order as in the OP's example.  He shows his sum in the last of the duplicate rows, whereas you are retaining the first of the duplicates and summing there.

Comment: Yes that's true

Comment: Thank you both of you so so so much for help. I will test those both codes what will work better for my excel and will let you know! :) I really appreciate it.

Comment: @JvdV do you think is it possible to put this code in a command button?

Comment: Ofcourse you can. Just assing the macro to a button.

Comment: One more question @JvdV and it might be stupid one :).. i try to run this code but it just informs me Run time error 424, Object required and then marks this point "If Not dict.Exists(arr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2)) Then".. what should i do differently

Comment: Got it :)! Thank you!

Comment: Question according to the code (one month later.. :) @JvdV ) I need to add also simple delete.duplicate command to the code, that macro will delete row if another row is the same with values from columns a to c.  So if columns A and B are the same, then corresponding values are added into columns C and D. But if columns A, B and C are the same then it just deletes the other row. I tried with this one, but it doesnt work correctly: With Sheet2  x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:D" & x).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlYes End With

Comment: @emppunen, I won't be able to assist till later today. I see you openened a new question on the matter which is fine too.

Comment: Should I add your name in to that question? :) @JvdV

Comment: A better thing would be to link to the other questions you had prior to your new one @emppunen. That way it's clear where your question comes from

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use a Dictionary object when looking for duplicates, and to work in VBA arrays when working with ranges.  Adds significant speed to the code:

```
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'   or could use late binding if this is for distribution
Option Explicit
Sub deDup()
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim myD As Dictionary, arrCD(1) As Long, skeyAB As String
    Dim I As Long, V As Variant
    
'declare worksheets and ranges
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet3")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet3")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(5, 7)
    
'read source into variant array
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp))
End With

'collect the data, add dups when needed
Set myD = New Dictionary
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    skeyAB = vSrc(I, 1) & "|" & vSrc(I, 2)
    arrCD(0) = vSrc(I, 3)
    arrCD(1) = vSrc(I, 4)
    
    If Not myD.Exists(skeyAB) Then
        myD.Add Key:=skeyAB, Item:=arrCD
    Else
        arrCD(0) = arrCD(0) + myD(skeyAB)(0)
        arrCD(1) = arrCD(1) + myD(skeyAB)(1)
        
        'can only alter arrays outside of the dictionary
        'since we delete original entry and then add back the modified,
        '  the desired order will be retained
        myD.Remove (skeyAB)
        myD.Add skeyAB, arrCD
        
    End If
Next I

'create the output array
ReDim vRes(1 To myD.Count, 1 To 4)
I = 0

For Each V In myD.Keys
    I = I + 1
    vRes(I, 1) = Split(V, "|")(0)
    vRes(I, 2) = Split(V, "|")(1)
    vRes(I, 3) = myD(V)(0)
    vRes(I, 4) = myD(V)(1)
Next V

'write results to worksheet
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .Style = "Output"
End With
    
End Sub
```

[image]

This transformation can also be done using `Power Query` aka `Get & Transform` available in Excel 2010+

- Get from `Range/Table`
- Reverse Rows
- Group by Columns 1 and 2
- Aggregate with Sum function for columns 3 and 4

[image]

- Reverse the rows

#### M-Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Column2", Int64.Type}, {"Column3", Int64.Type}, {"Column4", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Reversed Rows" = Table.ReverseRows(#"Changed Type"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Reversed Rows", {"Column1", "Column2"}, {{"sumC", each List.Sum([Column3]), type number}, {"sumD", each List.Sum([Column4]), type number}}),
    #"Reversed Rows1" = Table.ReverseRows(#"Grouped Rows")
in
    #"Reversed Rows1"
```

And, if you didn't care about the order, you could just use a regular Pivot Table.

Comment: This is definately also a nice approach Ron.

Comment: @JvdV Tks. I frequently use a Class for complex data. As you show, it can be used here also.

Comment: Your array approach might just be as good, if not better. I have no idea if it would affect speed on huge files though.

Comment: @JvdV I've never tested, so don't know.  This process can also be done using Power Query (just added that to my answer).

Comment: @JvdV OK I tested your approach vs my approach using a hi-res timer.  On 100,000 entries, your approach took about 2.1 seconds, mine took about 0.4 seconds.

Comment: Wow, that's quite significant in terms of percentage. Nice Ron

Comment: @JvdV Oops.  The data changed inadvertently when I re-ran the test. I'm going to delete that last comment of mine pending retesting.

Comment: @JvdV As I finally realized, that ten-fold speed change was related to an inadvertent data change.  It really is 0.4 seconds and not 0.04 seconds.

Comment: Still a great comparison! However, since using classes and dictionaries is like a new ground to uncover, there might be a more sensible way of using classes. I'll keep trying in the future :).

Comment: Can I ask @RonRosenfeld .. you set a range Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(5, 7) what did you meant with those cells?.. Im sorry for stupid question

Comment: @emppunen That's the cell in the upper left corner of the range where the results will appear. You can edit wsRes and rRes to be wherever you choose in your work book.

Comment: Obviously I meant it's new ground to uncover for me ;)

Comment: Hi again @RonRosenfeld :) I try to run the code but it just gives me type mismatch.. do you know what that means?

Comment: @emppunen Yes. You're passing the wrong kind of data to a variable. Check the line at which the error appears as well as the data and variable (or function) involved.