# Sum corresponding columns and delete duplicates without changing data in sheet1 (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have an excel with sheet 1 and 2. My goal is to create a macro that will delete duplicates and in certain situations add corresponding values into right cells. I have columns from A to F. If columns from A to C are duplicate with another row, macro will delete another row and add corresponding values to columns E and F. But if columns A to D are the same, then macro will just delete another row, without summing. (There is class module but I didnt post it here :) ) Here is more background info [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391896/vba-how-to-delete-dupicate-row-and-sum-corresponding-values-to-right-columns/58393679?noredirect=1#comment104125024_58393679) (Code is almost the same as in the link, but now my problem is to add other delete.duplicate command to the code)

```
Here is an example:
Sheet1          Sheet2
A B C D E F     A B C D E F
1 2 2 3 3 3     1 2 2 7 3 3
1 1 1 1 1 1     1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 3 3 3     
1 2 2 4 3 3
```

Now macro has deleted row 3 because it is a duplicate with row 1 (columns A to D are the same). Macro has also deleted row 4 and added corresponding values to row 1 (columns A to C are the same). This code works well when it needs to add duplicates and delete another row, but it doesnt delete duplicates if columns from A to D are the same. I dont know how to change the code that it would work.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim x As Long, arr As Variant, lst As Class1
Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Sheet1
    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = .Range("A1:F" & x).Value

 End With

With Sheet2

    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:F" & x).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4), Header:=xlYes

End With

For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If Not dict.Exists(arr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2) & "|" & arr(x, 3)) Then
        Set lst = New Class1
        lst.Col1 = arr(x, 1)
        lst.Col2 = arr(x, 2)
        lst.Col3 = arr(x, 3)
        lst.Col4 = arr(x, 4)
        lst.Col5 = arr(x, 5)
        lst.Col6 = arr(x, 6)
        dict.Add arr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2) & "|" & arr(x, 3), lst

    Else
        dictarr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2) & "|" & arr(x, 3)).Col5 = dictarr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2) & "|" & arr(x, 3)).Col5 + arr(x, 5)
        dictarr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2) & "|" & arr(x, 3)).Col6 = dictarr(x, 1) & "|" & arr(x, 2) & "|" & arr(x, 3)).Col6 + arr(x, 6)

   End If
Next x

With Sheet2
    x = 1
    For Each Key In dict.Keys
        .Cells(x, 1).Value = dict(Key).Col1
        .Cells(x, 2).Value = dict(Key).Col2
        .Cells(x, 3).Value = dict(Key).Col3
        .Cells(x, 4).Value = dict(Key).Col4
        .Cells(x, 5).Value = dict(Key).Col5
        .Cells(x, 6).Value = dict(Key).Col6

        x = x + 1
   Next Key
End With
End Sub
```

And I dont want to change the data in sheet1. Thank you for your help, Im very new for coding and VBA, so help is needed.

Comment: I think you meant to link to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58835358/9758194) recent question of yours instead of the current link you put up? Also please note that: `.Range("A1:F" & x).RemoveDuplicates` is under the `With Sheet2` and not under `With Sheet1`.

Comment: No, I meant the other one :) I have different excel things going on :D and I need to remove duplicates from sheet 2 because I want to keep the data same in the sheet 1 and macro will do changes in sheet 2.. do I explain clearly or not quite..

Comment: Well, then your code where you `RemoveDuplicates` should work. It does for me. It's not clear what exactly isn't working then

Comment: it sums up values on column E and F and it should just delete the another row without summing anything..

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not clear at all. Your comment contradicts your post. Maybe it's lost in translation but you said: "`This code works well when it needs to add duplicates and delete another row, but it doesnt delete duplicates if columns from A to D are the same`" which makes not much sense

Comment: So you first want to delete duplicates in column A-C, then run the rest of your macro, and afterwards delete duplicates A-D?

Comment: I think the order has to be other way, because if there is a duplicate in A-D then it will delete duplicate row but if there is duplicate A-C then it will delete the row AND sum corresponding values in column E and F.. complex :D

Comment: It's so complex that I lost track of what you actually are trying to do. Will delete the below, hopefully you can get your code sorted =)